# Azure, Easy Tables, CRUD + Search Operations in UWP

Tags: c#, search, uwp, crud, azure-mobile-services

**Azure Mobile Apps Easy Tables**

There is some articles on the net about how to use Azure's Easy tables for UWP data storage. Like these ([kinani95.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/backend-your-application-with-azure-for-free/](https://kinani95.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/backend-your-application-with-azure-for-free/))

but there are only Insert & Delete examples. Seems I understand Insert item method...

```
try
{
    Clients newClient = new Clients()
                {
                    Name = NameTxtBox.Text,
                    Surname = SurnameTxtBox.Text,
                    PK = PKTxtBox.Text
                };
    await clientsVM.insertClient(newClient);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString());
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

...but with delete - nope.

So what is the best way to implement Update|Delete functional to manipulate with data in tables.

I would be very grateful for the example code, how to remove, or get - change - to update the data. Or at least some documentation to implement stuff I said previously.

Q2: Can tables be 'queried' to search specific data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all CRUD operations on the data (Create, Read, Update, Delete). For examples of how to do query and update, see [How to use the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#querying).